# "undefined reference to SD" with SdFat library

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card

is there any way to rename a file in sd card without using **SdFat**? Thank you
im getting error when inclung the

```
    #include <SPI.h>
    //#include <SD.h>
    #include <SdFat.h>
    extern SdFat SD;
```

the error msg was "Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
"

```
Local\Temp\ccZn9IeW.ltrans2.ltrans.o: In function FatVolume::init(unsigned char) [clone .constprop.18]': \Arduino\libraries\SdFat\src/FatLib/FatVolume.cpp:439: undefined reference to SD' \Arduino\libraries\SdFat\src/FatLib/FatVolume.cpp:440: undefined reference to `SD'
```

Comment: Looks like you did not add this library the correct way. Please give more information: your IDE, your board, your settings and folder structure of your SdFat library.

Comment: The standard arduino sd library can not rename a file. The sdfat library can rename a file. If you want to rename a file, then you have to use the sdfat library.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `extern` keyword from `SdFat SD;` because it tels the compiler that the variable is defined elsewhere and it is not and the linker then can't find it.